# Temporarily syntax highlighting combined with query-replacements

Tags: faces

In latex-mode many macros comes with syntax highlighting. For example:

[image]

where the argument of the command/macro `\bibitem` (Fisher:99) has `font-lock-constant-face`.

I need to do something similar with my own macros. E.g., if I have the string

```
\mymacro{argument}
```

I need to fontify the string "argument" so the function (face-at-point) will give me the output `my-custom-face`. Plus, I need to do it "temporarily". Indeed I need to do it during the running of my scripts. **After that I need to restore the original face.**

I'm not interested in the visual effect of the `face`. I only need the function (face-at-point) to return `non nil` when the pointer is on the argument of my macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(highlight-regexp)`/`(unhighlight-regexp)` solved my problem. Here's, as an example, a piece of code that shows what I want to achieve.

```
(unwind-protect
    (save-excursion
      (highlight-regexp "\\\\mymacro{[^}]+}" 'font-lock-keyword-face)
      (when (string-match "TARGET_REGEXP" (buffer-string))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward-regexp "TARGET_REGEXP" nil t)
      (redisplay t)
      (unless (string= (face-at-point) "font-lock-keyword-face")

        (save-excursion
          (let ((b (copy-marker (match-beginning 0)))
            (e (copy-marker (match-end 0))))

        (perform-replace (match-string 0)
                 "TARGET_MOD"
                 t nil nil 1 nil b e )))))))

      (unhighlight-regexp "\\\\mymacro{[^}]+}"))
```

So I'll be asked for a replacement for all istances of "TARGET_REGEXP" (that may be a regexp) but "\mymacro{TARGET_REGEXP}".